# Euler equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

What's the relationship between the incompressible, free surface euler equations and the euler equations?

Are the latter just the former when the free surface is identically zero?

Answer (score 1):

*Euler equations* is a term for a **class** of PDEs from fluid dynamics. Their prominent common feature is absence of viscosity.

The PDEs within  this class can be classified further as:

1. Incompressible fluid (constant density, zero divergence of velocity) or compressible fluid (all others)
2. Fluid with free surface (think of water waves splashing) or without free surface (think of water flowing in a pipe).

Comment: Thanks! So I think the answer would be yes. I just got a bit thrown off by the evolution equation for the free-surface when I was trying to check that the well-known 3d Euler equations are obtained from the free-surface 3d Euler equations when one sets the free-surface equal to zero.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what "setting surface to zero" means. If you mean that the top surface of the fluid is set to be $z=0$, that would mean it's no longer a free surface, just a part of the boundary of the region containing the fluid.

Comment: In the free-surface Euler system, there is an evolution pde for the free surface $\eta(t,x,y)$, given by  $$\frac{D\eta}{Dt}=u_3\,\,\,\text{on}\,\,\,z=\eta(t,x,y).$$ I wanted to set $\eta\equiv 0$ to check that this system would reduce to the usual Euler equations. From what you say, it should. What is throwing me off is that setting $\eta\equiv 0$ gives $u_3\equiv 0$ on $z=0$, which kills the $z-$component of the momentum equations. Thanks.

Comment: It should reduce: eliminating $\eta$ you get the condition $u_3=0$ on $z=0$, impermeable boundary.

Comment: Exactly. I see, so zero free surface only makes sense with non-slip boundary conditions? or just the $z-$component of the velocity would have to be zero on the entire $xy-$plane?

Comment: The condition $\frac{D\eta}{Dt}=u_3$ leads to $u_3=0$, so only $u_3$ has to be zero. The horizontal velocity may be nonzero at the boundary.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know the 2d Euler equations were equivalent to the 3d free-surface EE with zero free surface and no gravity. Thanks.

Comment: Um, I don't think they are equivalent.  Notice that $u_3=0$ is enforced only on the boundary $z=0$. The fluid can still have upward and downward velocities underneath the surface. It's still a 3D problem.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I keep thinking $u_3$ vanishes everywhere, not just at $z=0$, for some reason. I get it. Much obliged!